# How to scrape the values of the n-th column of a table with pure JS?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, casperjs

I've been looking for this answer on the site, but all the answers seems to be jQuery specific.

I'm building a scraper using a Casper JS, and I can't find the right method to select the values of a column n, where n is an arbitrary number specified by me.

I'm selecting the table specifically this way:

`document.querySelector('table.table-responsive.table-noborder');`

and I get back a [TableElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) but from there, I don't know how to move forward to get the contents of a specific column, without having to iterate the whole table (which is what I'm ultimately doing to get the data)

Thanks!

Comment: You could access the `children` property of the TableElement and try to assume that the only children are going to be `<col>` elements and then go firectly to the n-th index but this is obviously very error prone. You are not going to able to avoid iterating to create a robust solution.

Comment: HTML tables are organized into rows, so you cannot just return all the values of a column without iterating. You can of course capsule the iteration in a function, which is fine if you ask me. Is there some other problem that you have? You could have shown a part of your code. The `<col>`-element does not hold data, but rather it applies styles to the `<td>` of that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own function that plugs nicely into casper. This iterates over the nth `td` or `th` in all the rows and writes the value of the innerText property into a result array:

```js
casper.tableColumnText = function(tableSelector, columnNumber, withHeader, merged){
    // columnNumber starts with 1
    var texts = this.evaluate(function(tableSelector, columnNumber, withHeader){
        var headerFields = document.querySelectorAll(tableSelector + " > thead > tr > th:nth-child("+columnNumber+")"),
            bodyFields = document.querySelectorAll(tableSelector + " > tbody > tr > td:nth-child("+columnNumber+")"),
            result = [];
        if (withHeader) {
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(headerFields, function(headerField){
                result.push(headerField.innerText);
            });
        }
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(bodyFields, function(bodyField){
            result.push(bodyField.innerText);
        });
        return result;
    }, tableSelector, columnNumber, withHeader);
    if (merged) {
        return texts.join(' ');
    }
    return texts;
};
```

`tbody` will be injected by the browser (phantom) even if it is not present in the original markup.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `document.getElementsByTagName('table')[m]` to reach your relevant m'th index table.

Same way, you can traverse inside the table, and get the text content by innerHTML or nodeValue

```
document.getElementsByTagName('table')[2].getElementsByTagName('tr')[1].childNodes[0].innerHTML
document.getElementsByTagName('table')[2].getElementsByTagName('tr')[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```